# Как добавить заливку на фон

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Надо вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<section class="promo">
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">
        <div class="logo__text">
          Your Logo
        </div>
      </a>
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="nav__list">
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Servicing</a></li>
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто залить `.header` белым цветом

```css
.header { 
  background-color: white;
}
```

Если вы хотите залить именно блок навигации белым цветом, то напишите

```css
.header .nav {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.nav__list,
.header {
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav__list>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.promo {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/2000/1000') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="promo">
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">
        <div class="logo__text">
          Your Logo
        </div>
      </a>
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="nav__list">
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Servicing</a></li>
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</section>
```

Но у вас неправильная html структура, с ней далеко не уедешь, я бы сделал примерно так, с этим можно работать:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.header {
  padding: 15px 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header .nav__list {
  display: flex;
}

.header .nav__list>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header__container>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.intro {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.promo {
  flex: 1;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.promo::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">

  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__container">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">
          <div class="logo__text">
            Your Logo
          </div>
        </a>
        <nav class="nav">
          <ul class="nav__list">
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Servicing</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="promo">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </section>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно тебя понял то попробуй добавить вот этот css.

```
.header { 
  background-color: white;
}
```

или отредактируй html

```
<section class="promo">
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header" style="background-color: white">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">
        <div class="logo__text">
      Your Logo
    </div>
  </a>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="nav__list">
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Servicing</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Мне надо залить блок навигации белым цветом.